# How to start a session, and then retrieve the session variable?

Tags: php, session

First and foremost, I have looked throughout the site and haven't been able to find a solution that works for my program.

Saying this, I am trying to create an authentication page that starts a session, and will save a username from a login page as a session variable. Then, I want my thrid page to retrieve the username session variable.

This is my Form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Test</title>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Log in with your username and</h1>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="formauth.php">
 <div class="form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
            <label for="card">Username:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter username here">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
 <div class="form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
            <label for="card">Password:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="enter password here">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
 <div name="buttons" class="col-sm-offset-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my authentication page. For some reason, I can't get this to save the username that is input into the form as a session variable.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'] =$user_name;
  if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
      isset($_POST['password']))
  {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];
    require_once "login.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pwd, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
    $query = "Select Password from Users where Username = '$user'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $result->close();
        $conn->close();
        header('Location: http://localhost/FormAuth/loginForm.html');

    }
    else {
        $rows = $result->num_rows;
        $result->data_seek(0);
        $p=$result->fetch_assoc()['password'];
        if ($p == $password) {
            header("Location: http://localhost/FormAuth/afterlogin.php");
        }
        else {
            $result->close();
            $conn->close();
            $result->close();
            $conn->close();
            header('Location: http://localhost/loginForm.html');
        }
    }
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

  }
  else
  {
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();
    header('Location: http://localhost/loginForm.html');
  }
?>
```

Now for my third page, I can't retrieve the username session variable.

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
echo "Username is: ".$_user_name['username'] . "<br>";
echo "Test, I made it here!";
}else{
echo "You not logged in.";
}

?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in:

```
Username is:
Test, I made it here!
```

Comment: Session should be started before any output

Comment: @u_mulder on my third page? So should I start the session before the <html> <head> etc tags?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks, I have added those edits to the question. The problem still exists and I still receive the same output as before

Comment: In your second page `session_start();  $_SESSION['username'] =$user_name;` what is `$user_name`?

Comment: @u_mulder should I set that to $user, since that is the variable name for posting the username? I believe that should be changed.

Comment: error reporting and `var_dump();` - two of your best friends ;-) oh, and viewing your html source also and checking for errors on the queries.

Comment: btw; I hope you're not intending on going live with this, are you? It's totally unsafe.

Comment: @Fred-ii- absolutely not. Just trying to teach myself the basics.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. Everyone seemed to help input a line of code here and there to help the final product work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user_name;

    if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
        isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
```

Do this one instead:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['username'] =  $user;
```

**EDIT: The third page:**

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Username is: ".$_SESSION['username'] . "<br>";
    echo "Test, I made it here!";
} else {
    echo "You not logged in.";
}
?>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Now I seem to have a problem with my third page. Now it outputs: "You are not logged in" Could this be a problem with my if (isset) on the third page?

Comment: Not a real good solution, because he put username in session without test password in his database.

Comment: The third page should be : if (isset($_SESSION) instead of if(!isset)

Comment: i think session must only be set when the entered password with that from database.

Comment: regarding auth problem on 3rd page, your condition check is wrong `if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {` must be `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {`. check my answer below where all these points are covered

Comment: yea i saw that. it wasn't edited by the time i commented

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check whether the posted values are set or not.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
      ...
```

Then, only when the passwords match, set the `session` variable `$_POST['username']` before redirecting.

```
    if ($p == $password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] =$user;
        header("Location: http://localhost/FormAuth/afterlogin.php");
    }
```

Then you can access your set session variable `$_SESSION['username']` on any page provided you use `session_start();`. Take the third page for instance,

```
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        // proceed to account dashboard / your required page
    } else {
        // redirect to login page / index
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set username in session **after check username and password in your database**.

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['username']) &&
      isset($_POST['password']))
  {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pwd = $_POST['password'];
    require_once "login.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pwd, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
    $query = "Select Password from Users where Username = '$user'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        $result->close();
        $conn->close();
        header('Location: http://localhost/FormAuth/loginForm.html');

    }
    else {
        $rows = $result->num_rows;
        $result->data_seek(0);
        $p=$result->fetch_assoc()['password'];

        if ($p == $pwd) { // use $pwd instead of $password
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user; // set username here
            header("Location: http://localhost/FormAuth/afterlogin.php");
        }
        else {
            $result->close();
            $conn->close();
            $result->close();
            $conn->close();
            header('Location: http://localhost/loginForm.html');
        }
    }
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();

  }
  else
  {
    $result->close();
    $conn->close();
    header('Location: http://localhost/loginForm.html');
  }
?>
```

And In your **third part**, **check if your username is set in session** before try to display it:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo "Username is: ".$_SESSION['username'] . "<br>";
}
```